# Active followed by passive voice

Tags: commas, passive-voice

- Smith is lying there watched patiently by Jones.

Am I right that this is two clauses, and that the second is a dependent clause in the passive voice?

Should there be a comma between them, and if so why?

Comment: Hmm. It could be a compound predicate: "Smith is lying there" + "Smith is watched patiently by Jones."

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a shortening of *Smith is lying there being watched patiently by Jones*, which makes use of a *present passive participle*. The participle functions as an adjective modifying Smith.

But as Scott mentioned, it could also be a compound predicate — that is, it is a shortened combination of *Smith is lying there* and *Smith is being watched patiently by Jones.*